# Question aboutPartial Fractions

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

for example:
$$\frac{{{x^2} + 4}}{{x\left( {x + 2} \right)\left( {3x - 2} \right)}}\, = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{{x + 2}} + \frac{C}{{3x - 2}}$$

first method is:

$${x^2} + 4 = A\left( {x + 2} \right)\left( {3x - 2} \right) + Bx\left( {3x - 2} \right) + Cx\left( {x + 2} \right)$$
but it is hard and take much time to find A,B,C

second method(Substituting the roots, or "zeros") is:

\begin{align*}x & = 0 \,\,\,\,\, : & \hspace{0.5in}4 & = A\left( 2 \right)\left( { - 2} \right) & \hspace{0.5in} & \Rightarrow  & \hspace{0.25in}A & =  - 1\\ x & =  - 2 : & \hspace{0.5in}8 & = B\left( { - 2} \right)\left( { - 8} \right) & \hspace{0.25in}&\Rightarrow & \hspace{0.25in}B & = \frac{1}{2}\\ x & = \frac{2}{3}\,\, : & \hspace{0.5in}\frac{{40}}{9} & = C\left( {\frac{2}{3}} \right)\left( {\frac{8}{3}} \right) & \hspace{0.25in} & \Rightarrow &  \hspace{0.25in}C & = \frac{{40}}{{16}} = \frac{5}{2}\end{align*}

it is better and easier method for Partial Fractions. My question is why this method works? can you prove this method?

Comment: Two polynomials are equal if and only if they have the same value for all $x$. Thus substitution of any $x$ value should result in equality.

Comment: "*Why this method works?*"  So, by rewriting it as you had for your first method... if you plug in, say, $x=0$ then notice that the $Bx(3x-2)+Cx(x+2)$ both become zero since they have a factor of $x$ which you just plugged in zero for.

Comment: ok but it is root of denominator and (number/0) is obscure

Comment: ok,got it thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "second method" is the next step of the first method. At each of the zeroes of $$x(x+2)(3x-2)$$ only one of the ABC terms is non-zero so you can solve for each ABC easily.

Answer (score 1):

It works from there

$$f(x)={x^2} + 4 = A\left( {x + 2} \right)\left( {3x - 2} \right) + Bx\left( {3x - 2} \right) + Cx\left( {x + 2} \right)$$

indeed

$$f(0)=4=A(2)(-2)\implies A=-1$$

and so on.